# Delete objects from python workspace

Tags: python-3.x, memory

I want to delete all objects excepts a few and free up all used memory.

I do not want to delete any loaded packages (using `import`) though.

In my workspace, there are many objects so it is difficult to delete them manually.

Is there any method available to achieve this? Any pointer will be very helpful.

Comment: You can use `del obj1, obj2`, but will need to specify each object you want to delete. Also check [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html) on how to explicitly invoke the garbage collector using `inport gc; gc.collect()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I explicitly free memory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316767/how-can-i-explicitly-free-memory-in-python)